# Deps File Missing for Dotnet 6 Integration Tests

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, xunit

Before I start, I've tried all suggestions from the following and none work:

[Integration testing ASP.NET Core with .NET Framework - can't find deps.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131379/integration-testing-asp-net-core-with-net-framework-cant-find-deps-json)

https://zimmergren.net/unable-to-find-deps-json-dotnet-azure-devops/

---

So I'm trying to write some integration tests for dotnet 6. However, my `WebApplicationFactory` throws the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Can't find
> '/repos/subscription-info-api/tests/SubscriptionInfoApi.Tests.Integration/bin/Debug/net6.0/...
>
> System.InvalidOperationException Can't find
> '/repos/subscription-info-api/tests/SubscriptionInfoApi.Tests.Integration/bin/Debug/net6.0/testhost.deps.json'.
> This file is required for functional tests to run properly. There
> should be a copy of the file on your source project bin folder. If
> that is not the case, make sure that the property
> PreserveCompilationContext is set to true on your project file. E.g
> 'true'. For
> functional tests to work they need to either run from the build output
> folder or the testhost.deps.json file from your application's output
> directory must be copied to the folder where the tests are running on.
> A common cause for this error is having shadow copying enabled when
> the tests run.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureDepsFile() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(Uri
> baseAddress, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient(WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions options)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient()
> at SubscriptionInfoApi.Tests.Integration.UnitTest1.Test1() in
> /repos/subscription-info-api/tests/SubscriptionInfoApi.Tests.Integration/UnitTest1.cs:line
> 14    at SubscriptionInfoApi.Tests.Integration.UnitTest1.Test1() in
> /repos/subscription-info-api/tests/SubscriptionInfoApi.Tests.Integration/UnitTest1.cs:line
> 16    at
> Xunit.Sdk.TestInvoker`1.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.<<InvokeTestMethodAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/Runners/TestInvoker.cs:line 264 --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Xunit.Sdk.ExecutionTimer.AggregateAsync(Func`1 asyncAction) in
> /*/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/ExecutionTimer.cs:line 48    at
> Xunit.Sdk.ExceptionAggregator.RunAsync(Func`1 code) in
> /*/src/xunit.core/Sdk/ExceptionAggregator.cs:line 90

My actual test code is extremely simple:

```
   [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        await using var app    = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
        using var client = app.CreateClient();
        var       res    = await (await client.GetAsync("/alive-test")).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.Equal("Alive!", res);
    }
```

---

As per the suggestions, I've made sure I'm directly referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing -> 6.0.0` in my integration tests project. I've also tried the various tweaks to the `.csproj` files that were suggested but nothing seems to be working.

I'm stuck for things to try to debug this further, any ideas?

Comment: In the same boat as you.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You are probably targeting the wrong namespace for Program in your test file (like I was).

I had to add the following at the end of my Program.cs file (last line) to make it visible to my test projects needing it:

```
public partial class Program { }
```

An example can be found here: [minimal api testing example](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/main/src/MinimalApiPlayground/Program.cs)

Comment: Damn... good spot. Yeah it was looking at some testing Program class in an extension. Thank you :)

Comment: This got me twice and enough time passed that I forgot what I needed to do. Your post has now saved me twice. It wasn't that Program was private it was because it had pulled in Program from the Microsoft testing framework. (Ahh see this was the same issue that @oneManArmin had)

Comment: my Program.cs file for my minimal API hasn't namespace neither public class

Comment: It's working on ASP  .NET 6

Comment: This was definitely my issue.

Comment: Chatgpt suggested lots of things but not this simple fix :D

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem, although for an entirely different reason.

I am using .net 6 but I deliberately chose to use an implementation that actually has a `Program.cs` file.
When I copied the code from [the official MS integration test guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sut-environment), I let VS pull in all the dependencies. The dependency used to resolve the `Program.cs` was not my own (*PersonalSite* for the sake of this answer), but one of MS's own implementation:

[image]

A small error on my part, sure, but maybe I can help somebody out.

For those who actually need the partial class implementation gimmick, the MS integ test guide I linked lists guidelines to do just that.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW there is another approach that works as well (which doesn't require modifying code).

In your app's .csproj file add the following (Assuming your test project is called 'Tests'):

```
      <ItemGroup>
        <InternalsVisibleTo Include="Tests" />
      </ItemGroup>
```

This allows your `Tests` project to see your `Program.cs` file.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the bottom of your minimal API controller

```
public partial class Program { }
```

As explained from Microsoft Docs :

Tip
If you’re using minimal API configuration in your Program.cs file, by default the class will be declared
internal and won’t be accessible from the test project. You can choose any other instance class in your
web project instead, or add this to your Program.cs file:
]{custom-style=Code}`csharp // Make the implicit Program class public so test projects can access it public partial class Program { } [`

As PmanAce recommends in his answer above

Answer (score 1):

My issue was the wrong using statement:

I changed `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestHost;` to `using TestASPNetMVC`.

My solution consists of 2 OOB project templates: ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) named TestASPNetMVC and xUnit Test Project named TestProject1.  I didn't change the ASP.NET Core project.  Here is my test project in its' entirety:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using TestASPNetMVC;
//using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestHost;

namespace TestProject1
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        public UnitTest1()
        {
            var webApplicationFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
            _httpClient = webApplicationFactory.CreateDefaultClient();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/");
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Assert.True(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result));
        }
    }
}
```

As noted above by pmanace, you'll need to add `public partial class Program { }` to your SUT project if you're not using top-level statements.

Comment: Mine was also getting the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestHost` version. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

change your  Program class access specifier in your api  from internal to Public

Comment: Please try to add more detail to your answer.