# How to fix the Error of IntegrationTest doesnt work correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, integration-testing

This is an Integration Test for a simple API in asp .net core but I don't understand why it's not working

this is my error

> System.InvalidOperationException : Can't find 'C:\Users###\source\repos####ApiProjectSolution\IntegrationTesting\bin\Debug\net7.0\testhost.deps.json'. This file is required for functional tests to run properly. There should be a copy of the file in your source project bin folder. If that is not the case, make sure that the property PreserveCompilationContext is set to true on your project file. E.g 'true'. For functional tests to work they need to either run from the build output folder or the testhost.deps.json file from your application's output directory must be copied to the folder where the tests are running on. A common cause for this error is having shadow copying enabled when the tests run.

public class IntegrationTestingClass :

```
IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public IntegrationTestingClass(CustomWebApplicationFactory factory)
    {
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetCustomers_ReturnsOkWithCustomersList()
    {
        // Act
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/Customer/GetCustomers");

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
        Assert.Equal("application/json; charset=utf-8", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);

        var customers = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Customer>>();
        Assert.NotNull(customers);
        Assert.NotEmpty(customers);
    }


    [Fact]
    public async Task GetCustomerById_ReturnsOkWithCustomer()
    {
        // Arrange
        var customerId = 1; // Assuming this ID exists in the database

        // Act
        var response = await _client.GetAsync($"/api/Customer/GetbyId/{customerId}");

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
        Assert.Equal("application/json; charset=utf-8", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);

        var customer = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Customer>();
        Assert.NotNull(customer);
        Assert.Equal(customerId, customer.Id);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task CreateCustomer_ReturnsOk()
    {
        // Arrange
        var newCustomer = new Customer
        {
            CustomerName = "Jane Doe",
            Email = "jane@example.com",
            Address = "New York",
            PhoneNumber = "9876543210"
        };

        // Act
        var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/Customer/CreateCustomer", newCustomer);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task UpdateCustomer_ReturnsOk()
    {
        // Arrange
        var existingCustomer = new Customer
        {
            Id = 2, // Assuming this ID exists in the database
            CustomerName = "John Doe",
            Email = "john@example.com",
            Address = "New York",
            PhoneNumber = "1234567890"
        };

        // Act
        var response = await _client.PutAsJsonAsync("/api/Customer/UpdateCustomer", existingCustomer);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task DeleteCustomer_ReturnsOk()
    {
        // Arrange
        var customerIdToDelete = 1; // Assuming this ID exists in the database

        // Act
        var response = await _client.DeleteAsync($"/api/Customer/DeleteCustomer/{customerIdToDelete}");

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200
    }
```

this is my code Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integration testing ASP.NET Core with .NET Framework - can't find deps.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131379/integration-testing-asp-net-core-with-net-framework-cant-find-deps-json)

Comment: No i checked all answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code in your Project file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

OR [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131379/integration-testing-asp-net-core-with-net-framework-cant-find-deps-json)

Comment: I have it in my project

Comment: Do you have this file (testhost.deps.json) in your project ?

Comment: No How can i Add it?